# Tablet / phone app security in unsecured networks

Tags: web-application, network, android, ios

Although reluctant to use my laptop on unsecured networks, I at least know that without me launching any processes or logging into certain web pages, that I will not be sending any credentials over the unsecured network.

For phones and tablets processes can run in the background without users knowledge (unless they kill them knowingly). Additionally there is no way to know how whether these applications have any extra security when sending their credentials over the network.

As an example, on my ipad, is there any way of knowing what applications are sending information using credentials, and whether they are sending this information unsecured? Or would the best way to find out be to use something like wireshark to investigate this manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is obviously a trust issue. You believe (rightfully) that your devices establish connections you didn't ask for. You suspect (again, rightfully) that those connections aren't always encrypted and that your information may be eavesdropped on when using insecure networks.

Even if there was a way to ask the device what data is sent out, would you believe it?

Your best bet is, like you said, to set up your own wireless network and dump all the traffic. In my opinion, there are so many parts of the device that can communicate with the outside world (the OS, the installed applications, the baseband, ...) that you're really better off trying to enumerate the outbound traffic from a "black box" perspective.